# Count number of objects in list of dictionary where a key's value is more than 1

Tags: python

Given a list of dictionaries:

```
data = {
    "data": [
        {
            "categoryOptionCombo": {
                "id": "A"
            },
            "dataElement": {
                "id": "123"
            }
        },
        {
            "categoryOptionCombo": {
                "id": "B"
            },
            "dataElement": {
                "id": "123"
            }
        },
        {
            "categoryOptionCombo": {
                "id": "C"
            },
            "dataElement": {
                "id": "456"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to display the `dataElement` where the count of distinct `categoryOptionCombo` is **larger than 1**.

e.g. the result of the function would be an iterable of IDs:

```
[123]
```

because the `dataElement` with `id` 123 has **two** different `categoryOptionCombos`.

```
tracker = {}
for d in data['data']:
    data_element = d['dataElement']['id']
    coc = d['categoryOptionCombo']['id']
    if data_element not in tracker:
        tracker[data_element] = set()
    tracker[data_element].add(coc)

too_many = [key for key,value in tracker.items() if len(value) > 1]
```

How can I iterate the list of dictionaries preferably with a comprehension? This solution above is not pythonic.

Comment: You can't do this with a comprehension.  What you need to do is translate this to a slightly different data structure that makes this possible.  I'll build an example.

Comment: You can use defaultdictionary(list) from collection package. The key can be data_element and values can be coc. defaultdictionary(list) is a dictionary of list.

Comment: I'd suggest searching for "python flatten" to see how to recursively iterate through a bunch of nested iterables, and you can pretty easily handle doing something if a key of 'dataElement' is found. At that point it becomes easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
import collections
counts = collections.defaultdict(set)

for d in data["data"]:
    counts[d["dataElement"]["id"]].add(d["categoryOptionCombo"]["id"])

res = [k for k, v in counts.items() if len(v) > 1]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['123']
```

This approach creates a dictionary mapping `dataElements` to the different types of `categoryOptionCombo`:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'123': {'B', 'A'}, '456': {'C'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost a one-liner:

```
counts = collections.Counter( d['dataElement']['id'] for d in data['data'] )
print( counts )
```

Output:

```
Counter({'123': 2, '456': 1})
```

Comment: The categoryOptionCombo should be distinct as per the text in the question. This will produce the same Counter if '123' has two 'A'

Comment: You're right.  Yours is a better approach.  I'd like to leave this here demonstrating another option for similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

No need for sets, you can just remember each data element's first coc or mark it as having 'multiple'.

```
tracker = {}
for d in data['data']:
    data_element = d['dataElement']['id']
    coc = d['categoryOptionCombo']['id']
    if tracker.setdefault(data_element, coc) != coc:
        tracker[data_element] = 'multiple'

too_many = [key for key,value in tracker.items() if value == 'multiple']
```

(If the string 'multiple' can be a coc id, then use `multiple = object()` and compare with `is`).